# How to install Ubuntu Touch with a Windows computer?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch

Can I install Ubuntu Touch on my phone via a Windows 8 laptop? I think I'm only seeing instructions from a Unix-ish environment?

Answer (score 0):

As for OS X, you should install [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), and then install Saucy Salamander, and then, you can start your install of ubuntu touch from this virtualized Unix-ish environment.